# Error in est.vmax() : could not find function "est.vmax" in SDLfilter in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying to estimate the max velocity of a flight using `SDLfilter`'s function `est.vmax()`, but receive multiple errors when trying to run this code.

```
library(SDLfilter)
```

The only warning message I receive from loading this package is:

```
Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Option 'datatable.old.unique.by.key' has been removed as warned for 4 years. It is now ignored. Please use by=key(DT) instead and stop using this option.
```

(which is not relevant here)

However, when I load this library, it resets my working directly to the one I loaded at the beginning of the script.

Then, when I try to run est.vmax():

```
Vmax <- est.vmax(data)    
#Error in est.vmax(data) : could not find function "est.vmax"
>
```

Again, it resets my working directly to the one I loaded at the beginning of the script.

I have tried:

1. Restarting R/RStudio
2. Updating R/RStudio
3. Updating SDLfilter
4. Uninstalling/reinstalling SDLfilter

I would appreciate any advice here. I know there are a variety of ways to estimate max velocity, but I am planning to use other functions in `SDLfilter`, thus would like to have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took a look at the documentation for the library. I can't find the function est.vmax in the documentation, which explains your errro.

There is however a function vmax(), maybe they changed something and you should use this one?

Link to documentation file: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SDLfilter/SDLfilter.pdf

See page 33 for the documentation for vmax-function.

Comment: Thank you! I should have checked the documentation first. My colleague ran the above code and est.vmax() worked, so I did not think it was an incorrect function, but now I realize that they likely have an older version of the function.